# Вопрос: SOA и C#

Tags: c#, service

Вот устраиваюсь на работу, спросил о том, что за неделю повторить, в какую сторону смотреть. Мне сказали посмотреть в сторону `Service Oriented Architecture (SOA)`.

Изучаю С#, посоветуйте, что почитать (желательно на русском), потому что тема кажется немного запутанной. Заранее благодарю. (Есть бумажная книга по ***распределенным приложениям на С#, SOAP***, но это кажется немного не то).

Comment: Это как раз про то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно смотреть в сторону технологий `Web Services` и `WCF`.

Comment: пользуясь моментом, посоветуйте хорошую книгу по WCF для начинающих, сейчас читаю Juval Lowy - Programming WCF Services, но она достаточно сложна, можете посоветовать что-то по-проще?

Comment: Хорошо, а есть отличия WS & WCF?

Comment: WCF - более новая технология с более широкими возможностями, но с большим количеством подводных камней.